# Constraint custom PostgreSQL type?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to add constraints directly to a type in PostgreSQL?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4 and I have originally defined my type like this:

```
create type indoors_map_location as (x bigint, y bigint, z bigint);
```

I couldn't find a way to add constraints to my type definition [in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertype.html) so instead I solved this problem by defining domains that add constraints to existing data types, then used them in my composite type definition, like this:

```
create domain non_nullable_bigint bigint not null;
create domain non_negative_bigint non_nullable_bigint check (value >= 0);
create type indoors_map_location as (x non_negative_bigint, y non_negative_bigint, z non_nullable_bigint);
```

Is there a more direct way to solve this? Or is my approach common? Would you know if adding constraints to type definitions is a planned feature or has it been left out for a reason?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sure you can, you can `ALTER DOMAIN`. I do it quite a bit to change `CHECK` constraints. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdomain.html . You can't change the base type though.

Comment: @CraigRinger: yes, you are right. I was thinking about e.g. changing `varchar(30)` to `varchar(50)` - you need to be aware of that and then use a check constraint instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't consider typmods. Good point. It is an issue for domains over numeric and too, and there a constraint is less useful. Should fix that one day ...